# upward type inference vs downward type inference

Tags: type-inference

I am familiar to type inference.
`var x = 5;`
makes x to be of type int. But, what does upward type inference and downward type inference actually mean. Any help with simple example will be appreciated a lot.

Comment: Actually, i came to know about these while using dart.

Answer (score 2):

Bottom-up (upward)  inference is where the types of the constituent parts of an expression are known, and the type of the compound expression is inferred from that.  Examples:

```dart
var x = 5; // `x` is inferred to be an integer.
var y = someString + someOtherString; // `y` is inferred to be a string.

// `list` is inferred to be an array/list of strings.
var list = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']; 

// If `someFunction` is generic, its type is determined from `x` and `y`.
someFunction(x, y);
```

Top-down (downward) inference is the opposite: the type of the compound expression is known, and the types of the constituent parts are inferred from them.  Examples:

```
// `[]` is inferred to be a `List<int>`.
List<int> list = [];

// The type of `element` is inferred from the type of `list`, which in this
// case is `int`.
var squares = list.map((element) => element * element);
```

You should think of the direction in terms of an expression tree.  For example:

```
      operation
       /    \
argument1   argument2
```

Inferring the types of the operation from its arguments would be bottom-up; inferring the types of the arguments from the operation would be top-down. (This is similar to bottom-up vs. top-down parsing.)

Comment: you mean to say, if type is inferred from RHS to LHS, it is referred as upward inference, while the opposite is referred as downward inference.

Comment: @prabinmaharjan No, left-to-right inference is something else.  You should think of it in terms of an expression tree where parent nodes are functions/operators/etc. and the children below them are arguments.  It is similar to bottom-up or top-down parsing.